MPI program using Python multiprocessing not terminating worker processes properly
Description of the Problem:
I'm working on an MPI program in Python to distribute image processing tasks to multiple nodes for parallel execution. The goal is to efficiently process multiple images across different nodes in a distributed computing environment. Each image is processed using various image processing operations, such as edge detection, color inversion, and brightness adjustment.
In my MPI program, I have implemented worker processes as WorkerThread objects, which receive image processing tasks from a master node, perform the required operations, and send the results back to the master node using MPI communication. The main challenge I'm facing is ensuring proper termination of the worker processes after completing their tasks.
The issue arises when I attempt to distribute multiple images to different nodes for parallel processing. Despite sending a termination signal and attempting to join the worker threads, some processes continue to run indefinitely, leading to resource consumption and inefficient use of computing resources.
import threading
import queue
import cv2  # OpenCV for image processing
from mpi4py import MPI  # MPI for distributed computing

class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, task_queue, rank):
        super().__init__()
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.rank = rank

    def run(self):
        while True:
            task = self.task_queue.get()
            if task is None:
                print(self.name , " is done")
                break  # Exit the loop if termination signal is received
            image, operation = task
            result = self.process_image(image, operation)
            #self.save_image(result, f"{image}_{operation}_processed.jpg")
            print(f"worker {self.name} done from operation {operation} on image {image}")
            self.send_result(result)

    def process_image(self, image, operation):
        img = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        if operation == 'edge_detection':
            result = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)
        elif operation == 'color_inversion':
            result = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
        elif operation == 'increase_brightness':
            result = self.increase_brightness(img)
        # Add more operations as needed...
        return result

    def increase_brightness(self, img):
        # Increase the brightness of the image
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
        v += 50  # Increase brightness by 50 units
        final_hsv = cv2.merge((h, s, v))
        result = cv2.cvtColor(final_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
        return result

    def save_image(self, img, filename):
        cv2.imwrite(filename, img)

    def send_result(self, result):
        # Send the result to the master node
        MPI.COMM_WORLD.send(result, dest=0)

def save_image( img, filename):
        cv2.imwrite(filename, img)
def main():
    rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
    size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
    if rank == 0:
        # Master node
        task_queue = queue.Queue()
        # Add tasks to the queue
        tasks = [("image1.jpg", "edge_detection"),("image2.jpg", "edge_detection"),("image1.jpg", "color_inversion"),("image2.jpg", "color_inversion")]
        for task in tasks:
            task_queue.put(task)


        # Create worker threads
        workers = []
        for idx, _ in enumerate(range(size - 1)):
            worker = WorkerThread(task_queue, idx + 1)  # Corrected line
            workers.append(worker)
            worker.start()
            print(f"Worker thread {idx + 1} created.")

        for _ in range(size - 1):
            result = MPI.COMM_WORLD.recv(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE)
            save_image(result , str(id(result)) + ".jpeg")

        #task_queue.put(None)
        # Send termination signal to worker nodes
        for _ in range(size - 1):
            print("sending none to thread", _+1 )
            MPI.COMM_WORLD.send(None, dest=_+1)
            task_queue.put(None)


        # Wait for all workers to finish
        for worker in workers:
            print(f"thread {worker.name} is joined and out")

            worker.join()

    else:
        # Worker node
        while True:
            task = MPI.COMM_WORLD.recv(source=0)
            print("received the task is " , type(task))
            if task is None:
                print("i break here")
                break
            image, operation = task
            result = WorkerThread.process_image(image, operation)
            WorkerThread.send_result(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Expected Behavior:
I expect the worker processes to terminate immediately after receiving the termination signal and completing their current task. The main thread in the master node should be able to join all worker threads and exit gracefully.
Observed Behavior:
After sending the termination signal to the worker processes, some of them continue to run indefinitely. The program does not terminate, and I have to manually kill the processes to stop them.
Additionally, I noticed that when I run the command mpirun -np 5 python3 filter.py, where the number of processes (-np) equals the size of the task queue, everything works fine, and all threads terminate as expected.
I've tried various approaches to ensure proper termination of the worker processes, including explicitly sending a termination signal, joining all worker threads, and checking for any deadlock conditions. However, I have not been able to resolve the issue.
